# How to detect a "win" in a Minesweeper game?

Tags: java, minesweeper

I am working on a [Minesweeper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minesweeper_%28video_game%29) which I have pretty much complete.

The only thing missing is the detection of winning. What would be the best way to implement this? I know its going to be part of the actionlistener that detects clicks, at some point the last click should detect a winner.

Could anyone give me some ideas thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The player has won if

```
numUnopenedCells == numBombs
```

(where a cell is unopened if it is in its initial state, or flagged as a mine).

- If `numUnopenedCells > numBombs` then the player has unopened cells which are not bombs (i.e. some work left to do)
- If `numUnopenedCells < numBombs` then the player has necessarily "opened" a bomb cell and already lost.

---

> ***I know its going to be part of the actionlistener that detects clicks, at some point the last click should detect a winner.***

Yes, this snippet would be executed directly or indirectly by the action listener. I'd suggest you have a model of the game state, and in the `openCell(int x, int y)` method you check the above, and take the appropriate action.

Comment: +1 -- I just deleted my answer -- I saw what you meant in the end though.

Comment: in response to your last comment, minesweeper sometimes forces the user to guess.  In that 3 cell situation, there is no way to know which cell has the mine.  Eventually you have to guess.

Comment: might need to do parseInt() as well to force the values to both be integers.

Comment: I've been looking this for quite awhile regarding a technical mechanics of the game. So far I haven't found any except for the tutorials on how to play the game.

Comment: It's quite simple really: 1) Place N random mines on the field, 2) When a user clicks a cell, if it's a bomb, it's game over, if it's not, then show the number of bombs in the neighboring cells. 3) Special case: If that number is 0, you typically display it as blank, and do a flood fill on the entire area of neighboring 0-cells.

Answer (score 1):

If the opened fields are `#(all fields) - #(bomb fields)`.

Comment: I think you mean, "If the *opened* fields are..."